# ng-required not working as expected if parent div is hidden conditionally

Tags: angularjs, requiredfieldvalidator, ng-show, angularjs-validation, angularjs-forms

In my code I am using `ng-show` and `ng-required` in combination. But, `ng-required` is not working as expected even when the respective `$scope` variable value is set to `false`. Please find the code below

```
<div role="form" name="selectQuestionsForm" id="selectQuestionsForm" ng-form>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
        <label  class="control-label question-answer-label"
                  for="firstQuestionSelect">First question</label>

        <div>
            <select class="form-control nopadding">
                <option value="">-- Select --</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="showCustomQuestion.first" >
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="questionsText.first" ng-required="showCustomQuestion.first"
            id="firstQuestionInput" name="firstQuestionInput" validation-min-length="3" validation-max-length="100" />
        </div>
        <label  class="control-label question-answer-label"
                  for="firstAnswerInput">First answer</label>
        <div style="padding-bottom: 15px;">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="answersText.first" 
            id="firstAnswerInput" validation-min-length="3" validation-field-required="true" validation-max-length="100" required/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="securityActionBtnContainer" class="visible-md visible-sm visible-lg">
    <button id="saveBtn" type="button" ng-disabled="selectQuestionsForm.$invalid" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right"  ng-click="saveQuestion(selectQuestionsForm.$valid)">Save</button>
    <button id="cancelBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default pull-right" style="margin-right: 10px;" ng-click="redirect['cancel']()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

The `select` element have a logic to display the option and it is working fine. When we select the option 'Write my own question', the hidden `input` is displayed. If user choose any other question the custom question `input` is hidden and not part of the form element. But `ng-required` is still getting applied though the value is set to the `false` and respective `form` doesn't validate.

Please let me know what I am missing to make it work. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `ng-show` takes an expression but `ng-required` takes a boolean. Do you know the value of `showCustomQuestion.first`? how are you changing it in your controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`. Items hidden using ngShow or ngHide still exist in the DOM and will be processed by angular. It's just not visible to a user.